# JavaScript onclick Function call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

```
text += "<button id=next onclick=calendar(nextDate)>"
text += "<button id=next onclick=calendar(prevDate)>"
```

This code does not seem to run normally.
I do not know what the problem is.

```
function calendar(date) {  

    ...........

    text += "<tr>"
    text += "<td colspan=7>"
    text += "<button id=prev onclick=calendar(prevDate)>"
    text += "◀"
    text += "</button>"

    text += "<button id=next onclick=calendar(nextDate)>"
    text += "▶"
    text += "</button>"
    text += "</tr>"
    text += "</td>"

    text += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML = text;

}

calendar();
```

Comment: Do you have any error on browser console? if please share that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set the onClick function to this function, you are missing semicolons at the ends of your lines ";"

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

> ```
> text += "<button id=prev onclick=calendar(prevDate)>"
> text += "<button id=next onclick=calendar(nextDate)>"
> ```

- You do not use quotes to surround the values of the attributes
- You pass the strings `prevDate` and `nextDate` instead of their values, but since they don't have any quotes surrounding them, javascript will try to find these two variables, but it won't be able to (unless they're in the global scope)
- You don not use any semicolons `(;)`, this probably won't cause a problem but it's still a good idea to use them

Here are a couple of ways that allow you to properly pass the previous and next date:

- String Concatenation
- Interpolation
- Event Listeners

### String Concatenation

```
text += "<button id='prev' onclick='calendar(" + prevDate + ")'>";
text += "<button id='next' onclick='calendar(" + nextDate + ")'>";
```

### Interpolation (ES6)

```
text += `<button id="prev" onclick="calendar('${prevDate}')">`;
text += `<button id="next" onclick="calendar('${nextDate}')">`;
```

### Event Listeners

```
text += "<button id='prev'>";
text += "<button id='next'>";

// This goes after document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    calendar(prevDate);
});

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    calendar(nextDate);
});
```